# Why does ssh provide insecure off-host forwarding?

Tags: ssh, security, port-forwarding

In the local port forwarding invocation below,

```
[me@TunnelBeginHost]$ ssh -L TunnelBeginPort:TunnelEndHost:TunnelEndPort ViaUser@ViaHost
```

, given the fact that the portion of the tunnel between `ViaHost` and `TunnelEndHost` is insecure, prone to network sniffing and all that, why is `ssh` even providing such an option? Security being at the heart of `ssh`, shouldn't it have required authentication at the TunnelEndHost as well..., say with a (hypothetical) syntax such as,

```
[me@TunnelBeginHost]$ # Proposed syntax:
[me@TunnelBeginHost]$ ssh -L TunnelBeginPort:TunnelEndUser:TunnelEndHost:TunnelEndPort ViaUser@ViaHost
```

that would have ensured a secure tunnel between `ViaHost` and `TunnelEndHost` as well?

Likewise, for remote port forwarding.

Understanding the rationale behind this capability of `ssh` will help clear up any misconceptions I may have about `ssh`-tunneling, or about security caveats associated with it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Off-host forwarding is a part secure and part insecure feature of `ssh`, making it **overall an insecure** feature.

The `man` page of `ssh` **must** include an explicit caveat regarding this. Regrettably, it does not, as of version `openssh-clients-5.8p2-25.fc16.i686`.

Answer (score 2):

First, "*the portion of the tunnel between ViaHost and TunnelEndHost is insecure*" **is not a fact**. You assume that the end host will be connected over public Internet, but that's not always the case – I might be using the tunnel for HTTPS, it might be going over IPsec, an encrypted VPN, or just a physically secured cable connection. My virtual machine LAN is not prone to sniffing as long as I'm the only one having root on my own laptop.

Second, what @Xeross said – **how would you authenticate** in your proposed scheme? Using what protocol? The tunnel feature was created to support arbitrary TCP connections. What if the end host does not support SSH, or TLS, or your favourite protocol? If you decided to require SSH support on the end host, then the entire tunnel feature becomes practically useless as the user could just SSH to the end host directly.

Finally, **why not?** `ssh` cannot know the user's network conditions better than the user themself (as seen in the first paragraph), and adding arbitrary restrictions such as this might just hinder their work. `ssh` is here to help, but not to babysit, as is the tradition of Unix programs.

Comment: I'm assuming that (1) the network traffic to/from `TunnelEndHost` can be sniffed even if it be on regular, non-IPsec intranet; (2) the `TunnelEndHost` has `sshd` running, and that the command in the syntax proposed above would fail if not. Isn't it true that (insecure) TCP tunnels could also be created via a program like `socat`, so why should `ssh` volunteer for an insecure functionality as this?

Comment: *"...the entire tunnel feature becomes practically useless as the user could just SSH to the end host directly."* Not sure I follow you. The client and the server which are being connected via this tunnel may be inherently insecure, so having `ssh` on the endpoint would still help.

Comment: @Harry: "*I'm assuming that ...*" You are assuming arbitrary conditions again, and these assumptions are false for very many use cases.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly would this end-point authentication work, considering the end-point could be anything, HTTP, HTTPS, etc. (you get the idea).

If the traffic needs to be encrypted whatever protocol you're trying to send over the tunnel will have to take care of that itself.

Comment: The end-point authentication would work the same way it works for `ViaUser@ViaHost`, only that it would ask for 2 passwords: one for authenticating `ViaUser@ViaHost` (and it already does that presently), and another for authenticating `TunnelEndUser@TunnelEndHost`.

Comment: @Harry: What if you're tunneling *something other than SSH*?

Comment: @grawity Why do you ask this only in case of off-host forwarding?

Comment: @Harry because that's the case where you can't authenticate with SSH on the destination because the destination isn't SSH

Comment: *"because the destination isn't SSH"* In which case SSH shouldn't offer to build the tunnel to the destination. I guess, that was the whole point of my original question; namely: If SSH can't provide a **secure** end-to-end tunnel, then it shouldn't try to provide a part-secure-and-part-insecure one. OTOH, it could try to provide a secure end-to-end tunnel with an extra SSH authentication for the tunnel end-point as well. Insecure tunnels one could always build with `socat`.

Comment: @Harry why remove perfectly good functionality like that though? If the remote endpoint is also SSH you just use another SSH client to connect to your local tunnel port so I don't really see what you're getting at.

Comment: @Xeross I like the functionality, no doubt. But a non-secure feature offered by a secure tool like `ssh` (that obsoleted the `r*` tools) seems like a design anomaly to me. Even the `man` page has no explicit mention of this, which is why I posted the question in the first place. If one is a regular `ssh` user and not a security expert, it is easy to be misled into thinking that "because `ssh` is a secure replace for former tools, everything I do with it would be automatically secure, especially in absence of any warning to the contrary in its `man` page."